# App causes android OS data consumption increase daramatically

Tags: android

I am building an android application where there is an alarm service running every 24 hours to download one file (files are less than 1MB). When i check the data usage for my app i find it reasonable and low however the android OS is high (15MB per day). when i stopped my app from running the android OS is back to low. Any ideas what could this be caused by and how my app is affecting the Android OS data consumption?
Edit:

```
Intent myIntent = new Intent(AlarmService.this, AlarmService.class);
pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getService(this, 0, myIntent, 0);
AlarmManager alarmManager = (AlarmManager) getSystemService(ALARM_SERVICE);
Calendar cal = Calendar.getInstance();
cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 12);
cal.set(Calendar.AM_PM, Calendar.AM);
cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
cal.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
alarmManager.set(AlarmManager.RTC_WAKEUP, cal.getTimeInMillis(), pendingIntent);
```

Comment: It seems that your alarm service might not be working properly.Can you show some relevant code snippets?

Comment: i added the alarm code but the idea is that i tested it by deleting the file and it didn't download again all day until the 12am of next day. so downloading happened once per day @curious

Comment: I am using OS 4.2.1 @323go

Comment: Have you explicitly turned off backups in your manifest?

Comment: no i haven't...should i ? @323go

Comment: I would, just to eliminate that as a possible culprit.

Comment: Well i did and i still see 10 - 15MB per day under android OS and it is like 2 MB for 5 days without the app @323go

Comment: Hey, that's bizarre. At this point, I'd put the app on the emulator and sniff network traffic.

Answer (score 0):

There might be a bug in the OS I have noticed the same problem 
1)  When I use opera browser  android data use goes up as some sort of function of the data used by opera.
2)  This seems to only happens when using mobile data and not on wifi 
I am trying to pin point the exact cause and ultimately a solution to this problem (S3 running 4.1.2)